# Multiple Robots with slam_gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure about this, but I gather that the slam_gmapping package cannot combine the laser scans from multiple robots?

If this is true, does anyone know if there exists a ROS slam package that does this? I've done a bit of searching but haven't been able to find one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28514/multiple-robots-with-slam_gmapping/) by [pmwalk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1402/pmwalk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2012-02-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure about other SLAM packages that would support multi-robot mapping, but i can confirm, that GMapping is not capable of doing this.

In fact i would guess that none of the particle filter based SLAM variations (like GMapping) is suitable for this use case. Since the map you actually see is only the estimate produced by the currently highest rated particle there would be some kind of combinatory explosion of the needed particle count if odometry-noise from two or more robots has to be estimated. And since the initial offset of the starting points of the robots is not known, even more particles with guesses of this offset would be needed for a global map to align properly if one robot visits an area the other robot has already mapped.

You may have a look at graph-based approaches that maybe incorporate visual features that are globally unique (e.g. SIFT, SURF). But i really have no idea if there is a algorithm like this implemented in ros already. I would really appreciate if you could keep us posted about your findings later on.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmwalk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1402/pmwalk/) on 2012-02-26**:
That was my intuition, thank you! If I do find some solution or alternative I will certainly post it back here.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-01**:
Please mark the answer as accepted with the checkmark at the left. So others will know you have an acceptable answer.

**Comment by [pmwalk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1402/pmwalk/) on 2012-03-01**:
Ah thanks, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, *slam_gmapping* doesn't work with multirobot systems. I have tried it with [stage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/MakingMapsUsingStagesWanderController), the SLAM just doesn't start to work, hopefully we will have some improvement in fuerte (March 2012 release).

Probably the reason that *slam_gmapping* fails is that the communication between two (or more) robots is ambigious.

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1